# Creating database tables with no integrity Constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-key-relationship

Is there a good time to design a database without defining relationships using Foreign Keys, and let the relationships be established on the Application level using JOINS?

In what case would this be design be idea?

Comment: This would be a good design for tables in DB2 on MVS, back in 1986. Or now, in MySQL on Linux using the MyISAM engine, since neither of those enforce referential integrity.

Comment: Removing integrity constraints on your system is like smoking If you have not started DONT start. Even if you decide to quit the damage will linger for years. Remember data integrity is to ensure data conforms to a standard. If you want an one size fits all database with no constraints move to a NoSQL alternative. As a side note JOINS do not enforce or establish integrity. Without foreign key constraints you can still create orphan records for example. This is generally a very very bad idea.

Comment: Thank you guys for the info. About JOINS not enforcing or establishing integrity, i understand. But you can use JOINS to establish "relationship" for the sake of just trying to query data. E.g, if you have two tables with no referential integrity on the DDL level, but each have a field called PhoneNumber, you can establish a relationship between the two tables in a Query/JOIN like "select * from t1 JOIN t2 ON (t2.PhoneNumber=t1.PhoneNumber) WHERE t2.PhoneNumber = '773-111-2222'; Ofcourse, there is not true relationship between these tables, but you can still use a JOIN to query data on them,